# Nuget Security Vulnerabilities?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

By installing nuget packages, do we download source codes or binary files?

How do we check if the package is free from security vulnerabilities

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What if someone submits a 'malware' nuget package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19048295/what-if-someone-submits-a-malware-nuget-package)

Comment: See also: [Is there any way to use Nuget securely?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/7845/138322)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> By installing nuget packages, do we download source codes or binary files?

Yes, the binary files will be downloaded automatically.

> How do we check if the package is free from security vulnerabilities?

You can use dotnet.exe: `dotnet list package --vulnerable`. The link: [How to Scan NuGet Packages for Security Vulnerabilities](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/how-to-scan-nuget-packages-for-security-vulnerabilities/)